# Methods, destroy and fetch of backbone.js are not supported in Adobe aem cq6.3

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, aem

These backbone.js methods (fetch and destroy) were working fine in adobe aem CQ5.6, now I have updated to CQ6.3. Functionalities are not working now.

fetch method -

```
fetch({
    url: contextPath+"/bin/servletpath/updatemessage",
    data: data,
    add: true,
    cache: false,
    success: (successCallback ? successCallback : function(){
        self.allowRequests = true;
    }),
    error: (errorCallback ? errorCallback : function(){
        self.allowRequests = true;
    })
});
```

Comment: you call it like `model.fetch([options])` and receive an error? or what exactly does not work. Backbone's fetch uses jQuery's ajax method under the hood, does `$.get` e.g still work?

Comment: Not getting any response, continuous spinner icon displayed(waiting for infinite time), It is calling doGet() method of the servlet class which has void return type and this method is working fine

Comment: if you open the developer tools in the browser, is a get request send to your servlet, and something is returned? what shows the dev tool for the response?

Comment: It is not returning anything, message "This request has no response data available."  displayed in REsponse tab.

In header section status code is 200 OK

Comment: "This request has no response data available." wouldn't that mean that something is wrong with the sling servlet returning no data? I assume if there was any authentication errors, missing CSRF token or something, then you would not receive a 200 response. Do you have any other errors in the browsers console? Can you use Logger to see if the correct data is passed to the `getWriter` method in the servlet?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Now it is working . Provided my solution below in answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fine by adding complete as below.

```
complete: function(response){ self.allowRequests = true; }
```

Answer (score 2):

From the jQuery docs:

> Deprecation Notice: The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and `jqXHR.complete()` callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use `jqXHR.done()`, `jqXHR.fail()`, and `jqXHR.always()` instead.

They likely upgraded to jQuery 3.0